# How to hash a password?

Tags: c#, security

My next task will be to encrypt passwords. I am working at the database access layer and my co-worker has made this request: implement an [SHA-512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) hash on an empty method. How can I do this?

Comment: Do not. Leave password encryption to security experts. You will get it wrong, and then you will imperil your organization. Hire an expert; that is far cheaper than the cost of cleaning up the mess after a successful attack against the weaknesses you didn't know you were adding to your security system.

Comment: Hiring an expert depends on your level of risk. If you are storing private information for the masses and this password is all that stands in the way, yes look for an expert. Most of the examples listed below will suffice for your average non confidential information project.

Comment: @Eric - I'm assuming that you mean by that "use the implementation of SHA512 in .NET instead of creating your own", not "use the membership providers implemented in .NET for your security."  I can see some validity to both, but while I'd agree 100% with the former, I can see some situations where the latter is not really possible.  In fact, it never even occurred to me that someone would consider implementing their own version of SHA-512 -- thus your comment had me puzzling for a minute as to whether you meant I should contract out security in my apps to someone more qualified.  :-)

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA - The answers below are perfect, but I'd just like to add that Hashing is different from Encryption. Hashing is one-way and not recoverable; Encryption is recoverable if you know the key. You never encrypt a password, you always salt-and-hash them instead. @Eric is saying 'Don't encrypt, and certainly don't re-implement it'

Comment: @tvanfosson: I'm saying to stop working on this entire thing right now and hire an expert. Getting password security correct is about a heck of a lot more than getting SHA512 implemented correctly.

Comment: @hipplar: The amount spent on a security solution should be in proportion to the value of the resource being protected. If the resource is not valuable then you don't need a password system at all. If the resource is valuable enough to be protected with a password system then it is probably valuable enough to be protected with a *professional strength* password system, not an *amateur* password system.

Comment: @Eric - agreed and that is probably excellent advice to one who feels compelled to ask such a basic question on SO, but I doubt that will fly with my manager.  Perhaps a better question to you is "how expert do you need to be to use the existing tools to implement a security solution?"  Surely the bar is somewhat lower than "you need to be able to design/analyze a new encryption algorithm."  Maybe, a topic for your blog?  I'd be interested in reading your opinions in more depth.

Comment: question being discussed on M.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49608/how-do-i-answer-a-question-when-doing-so-might-facilitate-a-train-wreck

Comment: @Eric - "Hire an expert" is a bit glib and may be unrealistic in many situations.  The next problem is: where do you find such an expert and how du you ensure he has the necessary skills?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quite a simple process really:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringPasswordForExample);

using(SHA512 sha512 = new SHA512Managed())
{
    byte[] hash = sha512.ComputeHash(data); // Add Per User Salt as per the Below
}
```

`hash` now contains a non-reversable hash of the initial data that you wanted hashed. Also, check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512.aspx). A few notes:

- Always use a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) (the longer the better, and unique per user - Thanks Paul, good point.)
- SHA2* generation (and SHA in general) hash methods are built for speed, so they are not insecure, but they are not the most secure. Look at bcrypt as well as [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2813888/103385).

Comment: +1 from me, though it would be worth mentioning the salt should be unique per-password. And perhaps changing your example to include the salt

Answer (score 10):

You should use [bcrypt](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx), which is more secure for passwords than SHA512.

If you really need to use SHA512, you should use the [`SHA512Managed` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512managed.aspx), as other answers have mentioned.
Make sure to salt your hash.

Comment: interesting, not seen that before

Comment: don't you salt the plaintext before hashing?

Comment: @uncle brad: That's what I meant.

Answer (score 7):

> how to hash a password?

With a salt.  Really.

Never, **ever** do this:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringPasswordForExample);
```

But this:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringPasswordForExample + salt);
```

This is one the most misunderstood "trick of the trade".  Most people don't know what a "salt" is and when you explain it to them, they think it's pointless.

Truth is: SHA-512 or MD5 or some very weak hash, once rainbow tables are precomputed, doesn't make any difference.  SHA-65536, should it exist (I'm being facetious here), would be no better than any other hashing algorithm once rainbow tables are precomputed.

A big enough "salt" makes rainbow tables impossible:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

Note that even if you understand fully how hashes, salt and rainbow tables relate (and hence understand why the Wikipedia article states: *"A salt is often employed with hashed passwords to make this attack more difficult, often infeasible."*) there's a very high probability that your co-workers don't.  Just as it is very likely that most people up and downvoting in this thread don't understand this topic.

I've seen answers here on SO with 30 upvotes where someone who couldn't understand what a salt was kept up coming with techno-buzzwords to defend his position... And yet he had all these upvotes (too lazy to find the question but it was epic).

Comment: And you should use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` to create your salt for each new hash, and store both the hash and the salt.

Comment: A salt alone is not enough. The hash function should also be slow. Use PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt.

Answer (score 1):

[SHA512 Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512.aspx)

C# example from that page:

```
byte[] data = new byte[DATA_SIZE];
byte[] result;
SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
result = shaM.ComputeHash(data);
```

Comment: -1 for using plain SHA-512, which is fast. Use a slow key derivation function, such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt.